# Chrome: Call Javascript function from (system) command line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, command-line, terminal, remote-access

I need to call a Javascript function from a website running in Google Chrome / Chromium from the command line.

Is there any possibility to get access over the developer tools from outside via command line? Is there an extension I could use to execute code?

The most convenient way would be to have access to the Chrome developer console from the command line.

**Edit:**

To make it more clear:
Let’s say the website I’m on has this function defined:

```
function hello() {
  alert("hello");
}
```

I would like to call this function, but I don’t have access to the developer tools in Chrome. I can only access the Mac OS X Terminal (via SSH). It’s a setup in a gallery without keyboard. 
Some kind of pipe may be needed.

Comment: Your mean command line (CMD) in windows? why you not use google console?

Comment: What are the downvotes for? Maybe it's an odd question, but I wouldn't call it unclear or lacking research effort. It *could* benefit, **greatly**, from a "why."

Comment: @Cerbrus There are [all sorts of options](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) when *launching* Chrome from terminal. It's possible that's really what OP wants. Also note that "terminal" is a tag here.

Comment: I am talking about Terminal in Mac OS X. Basically I would like the code I enter there, e.g `chrome-pipe alert("hello")` to be executed in the developer tools console (in this case resulting in a popup).

Comment: @Pwdr: Why? You seem to have the dev console open already. Why not enter your code there?

Comment: @PaulRoub: Those options can be used in ordinary shortcuts, too. T.J: Without an answer to _"why"_, I'd call this quite unclear.

Comment: I agree with T.J. Crowder on this one @Cerbrus. It's pretty obvious that the user would like to be able to run dev-tools somehow from a client terminal (no clarified to be the Mac OS X Terminal) and run a function available on a web page using command line arguments.

Comment: I don’t have a mouse and keyboard on this machine. It’s a permanent setup in a gallery. I need this functionality to change the view of the website being displayed.

Comment: Wouldn't an wireless keyboard / mouse setup be easier?

Comment: @Cerbrus I’m using special hardware buttons. The viewer should not have the possibility to enter text.

Comment: A wireless keyboard you store in a secure location when not performing maintainance

Comment: @pwdr https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd install a [User Script](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) that runs on the page in question and calls that function. Set the page as Chrome's default, and at startup the page loads, the script runs, and all is well.

Comment: @Cerbrus The keyboard is no option in this setup.

Comment: @TinyGiant Thanks, that looks promising!

Comment: @PaulRoub It can not be called just once, the event is triggered via experimental interface by the user.

Answer (score 5):

After some more research I found [crconsole](https://github.com/sidorares/crconsole), which can be used to execute code in Google Chrome.

Chrome has to be started like this:
`open -a "Google Chrome" --args --remote-debugging-port=9222`

Answer (score 4):

The command line utility [chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli) can do this.

Using your code example:

```
chrome-cli execute '(function hello() { alert("hello"); }())'
```