# Windows 10/11 - Command line to launch browser (Google Chrome or MS Edge) with Index page to open + a string to be passed to the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Is there any way to launch either Google Chrone or MS Edge from command line with not only the page to be open (i.e. `index.html`) but also with a string to be passed to the JavaScript?

I found that this was doable in Internet Explorer using HTA but it appears such mechanism is not available in MS-Edge and (obviously) in Chrome.

Comment: For security reasons, I'm afraid that you can't implement such a requirement without using additional tools. For example, the `chrome-cli` and `crconsole` mentioned in the answer in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872239/chrome-call-javascript-function-from-system-command-line).

Comment: Thank you @XudongPeng for your response. I did find a way (still working on it) where your url would look like: `index.html?Par1=ABC`. Right now the problem is that the `?` character is converted to its exa representation and hence the page is not open at all. If within the URL input to the explorer I manually replace the exa representation with a `?`, it would appear that this solution does work. Still remains to extract the value of `Par1` within the JavaScript, but I also saw how this can be done.

Comment: If you find a solution to this problem, you can post your own solution as an answer, which will also help other community members with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...
After some search and assistance from this site (see RVRX's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76955069/batch-file-to-start-chrome-replaces-with-3f)), I found the way to do what I needed. The command line to be included in a small bat script with only two lines:

```
echo off
start chrome file://d:/MyDir/index.html?rt=%cd% --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%cd%
```

being `%cd%` the folder in which the script sits.

Within the Javascript, the value of `rt` is retrieved using the following code:

```
var G_Project_Root ;
var l_Passed_Params_String = window.location.search;
var l_Parsed_Params = new URLSearchParams(l_Passed_Params_String);
G_Project_Root = l_Parsed_Params.get('rt')
```