# Batch file to start chrome replaces "?" with %3F

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, windows-10

I have a simple Windows 10 bat file that runs Google Chrome with some switches and one input (the value of `%cd%`). The command is:

```
start chrome d:\MyAlbums\index.html?rt=%cd% --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%cd%
```

Upon execution, Chrome opens BUT the address shown in the address input bar became (see that "?" was replaces by its HEXA value):

```
file:///D:/MyAlbums/index.html%3Frt=d:/MyAlbums
```

and Chrome states that he file could not be accessed.

If I manually edit the contents of the address bar, replace `%3F` with `?` and press ENTER, the page appears as needed and all works as expected.

The question is: Why is the original "?" replaced and how can this be prevented.

Comment: `start "" chrome.exe "file:///D:/MyAlbums/index.html?rt=%cd:\=/%" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="%cd%"` is most likely better which I have not tested as I don't have `D:\MyAlbums\index.html` nor was posted the source code of this HTML file containing most likely JavaScript or referencing a JavaScript file loaded by the web browser on loading the HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell chrome it is a file by prefixing `file://` to the directory path. This will prevent URL encoding.

So `start chrome file://d:\MyAlbums\index.html?rt=%cd% --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%cd%` will be your full command.

Comment: The [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) requires `file:///` or `file://localhost/` at beginning of the URI on referencing a file on a local storage media like drive `D:` for being 100% valid. `%cd%` is in real also invalid in the URI as all ``\`` should be replaced by `/`, each space by `%20`, etc. Other characters must be also [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). But the hint in this answer is in general correct and Chrome makes most of the corrections automatically for a valid file URI.